# Detect end of image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a bunch of UIImages that consist of black and white book pages. I want to be able to "crop" or "cut" the image based on where the page ends (Where the white space begins). To illustrate what I mean, look at the image below. I want to crop the image programatically right after the word "Sie".

[image]

I am not sure how to go about this problem. I have gave it some thought however, perhaps detecting where the black pixels stop since it will always be black and white but not sure how to properly do this. Can anyone offer any insight or tell me how this may be done?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Picture doesn't seem to be appearing on my end. Could just be my network though, figured I'd mention it. +1, curious myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some python code I wrote using the Python Imaging Library. It finds the lowest black pixel, and then crops the image five pixels down from that y value.

```
import Image

img = Image.open("yourimage.fileformat")
width,_ = img.size
lowestblacky = 0
for i, px in enumerate(img.getdata()):
    if px[:3] == (0, 0, 0):
        y = i/width
        if y > lowestblacky:
            lowestblacky = y
img.crop((0,0,width,lowestblacky+5)).save("yourimagecropped.fileformat")
```

Python is available on nearly all operating systems, so I hope you'll be able to use this. If you want to crop the image right after the last black pixel, simply remove the "+5" from the last line, or change the value to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the image into pixel values. Start with the bottom line of pixels and look for black pixels. If some are found, the line is the end of the image. If there is no black pixel, continue to the next line of pixels.

Actually, "black" pixel is probably too simplified. A good solution would use a limit of gray (every image has some noise) or even better, a change in pixel contrast. You can also apply an image filter (e.g. Edge detection or sharpen) before starting the detection algorithm.